# Is it safe to remove linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi after upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04 - dependency error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel

I've just upgraded a raspi installation of 21.10 to 22.04
During installation there was a message about uninstalling the kernel package is the same as the one running and it may not be a good idea to do this as the system may not reboot. so I selected don't uninstall.

So all done and system reboots.

Now whenever I do `sudo apt install` I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi : Depends: linux-modules-5.13.0-1028-raspi but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I do `sudo apt --fix-broken install` then I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 10.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

doing `uname -r` gives me

```
5.15.0-1012-raspi
```

which is a newer version than the package it wants to remove.

listing installed packages with `apt list --installed |grep linux-image` gives me

```
linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi/now 5.13.0-1028.30 arm64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.13.0-1031-raspi/now 5.13.0-1031.34 arm64 [installed,local]
linux-image-5.15.0-1012-raspi/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0-1012.14 arm64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-raspi/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 5.15.0.1012.11 arm64 [installed,automatic]
```

So is it safe to remove linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi ?

Thanks

Comment: Try the command `sudo apt autoremove` and see if the old kernels are removed this way. This is the safest method.

Comment: Just continue with your `sudo apt --fix-broken install` that should fix it. It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely safe. Since you have upgraded to 22.04, the current kernel line is 5.15.0, and the 5.13.0 kernel packages are not needed anymore.

However, always leave a "backup" kernel on the system, so until the next kernel update (so you have 2 different 5.15 kernels) leave the last 5.13 be, just to be sure.

So you need to answer "Yes" (<kbd>Y</kbd>) at the `--fix-broken install` prompt. This will most likely fix your issue, and the package `linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi` isn't needed on your system anymore.